# BEM naming convention for nested tiny parts

Tags: css, bem

Just started coding with BEM naming methodology. I wondered how to name nested tiny parts.

I attached sample layout below, please take a look.

There are two `span`s inside `h3` and I want them to have different style.

Then shall I just name them like they belong to their parent:

```
class="en product-lineup__title-en"
class="non-en product-lineup__title-non-en"
```

or like they belong to their title (but it looks like BEEM...):

```
class="en product-lineup__title__en"
class="non-en product-lineup__title__non-en"
```

or just leave it blank then in CSS

```
.product-lineup__title span:first-child
.product-lineup__title span:nth-child(2)
```

Which is the best way or do I misunderstand BEM rule in the first place?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEM is a methodology about reusable blocks. If you see a visual pattern that is repeated in the UI, then you should consider to see it as a block, not an element. Elements are the block details.

For your wireframe, I suggest two blocks: the `lineup` block is responsible for the global layout:

```
<ul class="lineup">
  <li class="lineup__item"></li>
  <li class="lineup__item"></li>
  …
</ul>
```

In each `<li>`, there is an instance of a `product` block:

```
<article class="product">
  <img class="product__img">
  <h3 class="product__title">…</h3>
  <div class="product__text">…</div>
</article>
```

If you want to keep your current HTML structure, then you have a mix on `<li>` markups:

```
<ul class="lineup">
  <li class="lineup__item product">
    <img class="product__img">
    <h3 class="product__title">…</h3>
    <div class="product__text">…</div>
  </li>
  …
</ul>
```

Here the `lineup__item` CSS class is responsible for positioning the child block `product` in the parent block `linup`. A block should not position by itself (it wouldn't be reusable).

Then, your element `product__title` has two children `en` and `non-en`. With BEM, an element cannot be parent of other elements. But it can nest brother elements. You can do:

```
<h3 class="product__title">
  <span class="product__title-en"></span>
  <span class="product__title-non-en"></span>
</h3>
```

In the BEM tree, `title`, `title-en`, `title-non-en` are all child elements of the `product` block. It is the light solution.

But maybe you'll realize that this kind of dual titles is a visual pattern used outside the `product` block, or maybe just for clarity, you can decide to make a `dual-title` block for that.

```
<h3 class="product__title dual-title">
  <span class="dual-title__en"></span>
  <span class="dual-title__non-en"></span>
</h3>
```

Here the CSS class `product__title` is responsible for positioning the child block `dual-title` in the parent block `product`.

Comment: So what I needed was to see more `Blocks` rather than bothering myself about `Elements`. I wrap my head around BEM very well now, I think :)